# How to integrate changes from xml back to .idml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, adobe-indesign

I've created a template in inDesign and exported it to files with extensions .idml and .xml. After that I put these files into root of my project. What I want to do is to programmatically populate xml file based on Tags trough the code, and after that get back these changes to my template, so end user can see changes on frontend.

Exported xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
  <makeFirstAd>new value for makeFirstAd</makeFirstAd>
</Root>
```

Here is my part of code in c# related to updating xml file that is working

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string updatedValue = "new value for makeFirstAd";
            UpdateMakeFirstAdValue(updatedValue);
        }

        public void UpdateMakeFirstAdValue(string updatedValue)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get the path to the XML file located in the root of the project
                string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "CarIndexBrochure.xml");

                // Step 1: Read the XML file
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);

                // Step 2: Update the value of <makeFirstAd> element
                XmlNode makeFirstAdNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/makeFirstAd");
                if (makeFirstAdNode != null)
                {
                    makeFirstAdNode.InnerText = updatedValue;
                }

                // Step 3: Save the updated XML
                xmlDoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the process
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

How to get back this change to the template, so when user wants to open the template he can see the change visually ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var prefs = app.xmlImportPreferences;
prefs.importStyle = XMLImportStyles.MERGE_IMPORT;

var xml_file = File('/Users/me/temp/test.xml');
app.activeDocument.importXML(xml_file);
```

It updates the current INDD document. Then you can save it as an IDML-template

```
var idml_file = File('/Users/me/temp/test.idml');
app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.INDESIGN_MARKUP, idml_file);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer, your point of view is good, I want to update current document from xml, and then to convert to IDML. Let me check, I will let you know if this works for me.

Comment: So for this implementation I need InDesign Server, but I am working with standalone inDesign application where I created the template, exported as IDML and put it into root of project. Somehow I need to figured out how to implement pure logic if it is possible. I also tried to add COM reference InDesign type library, and when I want to create instance of Application, inDesign application runs, but I dont want to achieve that. Just update .IDML file based on changes from XML, and put it back to document so user end can see the changes on UI.

Comment: Well, I believe it can be done without InDesign. An IDML file is just a zip-packed xml-like file after all. But this task is beyond my expertise. Here is some docs: https://manualzz.com/doc/9627253/adobe-indesign-cs6-idml-cookbook and https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.173.8853&rep=rep1&type=pdf Probably all you need is to make two IDML file (original and changed one), unpack them and compare their contents.

Comment: Thank you, I will search trough the doc. I know what you are trying to say.. I already also tried that but there are some hard point to catch placeholders for some reason.

Comment: @Jakobson you won't be able to directly match the InDesign XML to XML in the IDML. The nodes can be found inside the xml files inside the Stories folder. The Root and  makeFirstAd will be encoded as <XMLElement name="Root> or something like that.

Comment: @user1754036 I am little bit confused, so when I saved the template, I only have .indd document and exported .IDML, there is no XML file, and then trough the code I converted .IDML file to XML, and there was Stories folder as you mentioned in the content of XML. Now from my point of view, after research and Yuri's advice I think that I need to unzip the .IDML file, find where nodes are located, and somehow change the value, and then zip back, but not sure if this workflow will work. Your statements are also quite correct.

Comment: Yes. Unzip the IDML, modify Story XML, then re-zip. This works, but it is only one way to do it. Using JavaScript API for InDesign to tell InDesign to make the updates to the file is another, perhaps easier, approach.